# This ip, site, mobile is not authorized...error when adding allowed android devices field

Tags: android, google-api, google-places-api

I have an android app that uses google places api to get near places...everything works fine when I leave the allowed android devices field for android api key empty...but when I add my custom certificate's SHA1 fingerprint and package I get the error that my app is not authorized...when I remove it again it works!

I think it is necessary to add this field because it prevents quota theft but why I am getting this error?
I am pretty sure of that the fingerprint and the package name are correct.

Help please

Comment: Show how you are getting the SHA1 fingerprint

Comment: Going to java\bin then opening cmd and typing keytool -list ...etc

Comment: Is this for your debug SHA1 or your release SHA1 for the keystore used to sign your release build?  Can you show the full command you're running?

Comment: Release...keytool -list -v -keystore "keystore path.jks" -alias my alias

Comment: Ok, and when it's not working for you, are you running the signed release apk, or are you running from Android Studio?

Comment: Both dont work I tried both

Comment: For running from Android Studio, you'll need to enter your debug SHA1 fingerprint.  As for the release signed apk, are you sure that you're getting the SHA1 from the same jks file that you used to sign your apk?  Are you on Windows or Mac or Linux?

Comment: I know it won't work in debug...but it should work in release. Yeah I am sure

Comment: Did you enter your API Key directly in the AndroidManifest.xml file?  Or do you have it stored in a separate xml file?

Comment: Directly...although I think I don't need it because I am sending the request and putting the api key there also

Comment: Oh, are you using the Places Web API, with the URL that returns JSON?

Comment: Yes exactly as you said

Comment: And what type of API key are you using?

Comment: Currently Android Api key

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're using an Android API Key.

For the [Places Webservice API](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/intro) you need to use either a Browser Key or a Server Key.

From the documentation:

> If your project doesn't already have a key for server applications,
>   create an API key by selecting Create New Key (under "Public API
>   access") and then selecting Server key.

Also, this is interesting since you found out this is not true, but the documentation also states:

> Note: The Google Places API Web Service does not work with an Android
>   or iOS API key.

Go in the Google Developer Console, click <kbd>Create new Key</kbd>, then click <kbd>Server key</kbd>
 or <kbd>Browser key</kbd>.

This is the key that you use in your URL that returns JSON.
If you also have a Google Map, use a separate Android key for that, placed in your AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: But I don't know what to put in the referrer or ip adresses...I dont have a website or a server...when creating any of the two you suggested I am asked to put either a referrer or an ip address before using it in production

Comment: @Dev When using the Places Web Service API from an Android app, you would just leave those blank.  Also, as you found out earlier, an Android key works as well if you don't enter any SHA1/package.  The API that you're using is not geared specifically for Android, it's actually meant to be used on websites, but people use it in Android because it can do things that the Android specific APIs can't do.  Just be sure to use a different Android key with SHA1/package entered for using Google Maps (enter that one in the AndroidManifest).

Comment: @Dev  I also just noticed that in the documentation, they explicitly state that it doesn't work with an Android API key.  You found out that if you leave the SHA1/package blank, it actually does work, which is very interesting.  However, just create a Server or Browser key, and use it strictly for this API, just to be on the safe side.

Comment: I don't use google maps...Just the places api...so you are saying it does not matter what kind of api I use and it's safe to leave that field blank?

Comment: I won't use an android api key...but should I leave the field blank?

Comment: @Dev well, for using this API in an Android app, it's really the only option!  Since the documentation says to use a Server key, just go with that.

Comment: I have seen that this server key doesn't work with release apk. At least that what is happening for me. Anybody have any clue about this  ??

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the [Places API Web Service](https://developers.google.com/places/webservice/) then you should use a Server key, as noted by Daniel Nugent above (please accept his answer, not mine).

In this case, best practice is to proxy the requests from your Mobile Application via an intermediate server.

If it is possible to do so, given your feature requirements, you should consider using the newer [Places API for Android](https://developers.google.com/places/android/), in which case you would be able to use an Android Key.

Comment: The new places api for android does not contain nearby search feature, that's why I am using the web service ... can you please explain more about how to proxy the request from the app via an intermediate server since I don't have a server